# For a group homomorphism $f: G \to G'$, show that if $H < G$, then $f(H) \leq G'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

This is an exercise from "Introduction to Abstract Algebra" by Timothy J. Ford. I really don't know where to start proving this, so if you could give me a *start* on how to do this, but not reveal the proof, that'd be great.

The questions is in the title, but I'll re-state it.

For a group homomorphism $f: G \to G'$, we wish to show that $H < G$ implies $f(H) \leq G'$.

I came up with this solution, if someone is able to verify it:

Let $a,b \in f(H)$, so $a = f(h_1), b = f(h_2)$ for some $h_1,h_2 \in H$

We wish to show $f(h_1)(f(h_2))^{-1} \in H$

$f(h_1)(f(h_2))^{-1} = f(h_1)f(h_2^{-1})$ because homomorphisms send inverses to inverses
$= f(h_1h_2^{-1})$ by the definition of a homomorphism

$f(h_1h_2^{-1}) \in f(H)$ because $h_1h_2^{-1} \in H$ by $H \leq G$.

Therefore, $f(H) \leq G'$.

Comment: Do you know the conditions that need to be satisfied for something to be a subgroup? Did you try showing that $f(H)$ satisfies them?

Comment: I know that the subgroup test states that for elements $a,b \in H$, if $ab^{-1} \in H$, then H is a subgroup. Is this what I apply to $f(H)$?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Take $a,b\in f(H)$, so $a=f(g)$, $b=f(h)$ for some $g,h\in H$ and get going.

Comment: I edited the question with a proposed solution. Does it look alright to you?

Comment: Looks good now.

Comment: Your proof needs one more thing! The subgroup test has another condition that's easy to forget. You *must* show that $f(H)$ is not empty! Otherwise it's a good proof, though. If you can quote that the image of a group homomorphism is a group, then another way to prove it is to remark that the restriction of $f$ to $H$ is also a group homomorphism, and has image a subset of the image of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of requirements for a subset to be a subgroup. You know that $H\subseteq G$ fulfills all of them. There is a list of requirements for a function to be called a homomorphism. You know that $f$ fulfills them.

There is a list of requirements for a subset to be a subgroup. You are asked whether $f(H)\subseteq G'$ fulfills this list. Use the facts in the above paragraph to show that the requirements are indeed fulfilled.